# Trying to develop a forked project for use with Angular

Tags: angular, fork, rollup

I am trying to make a PR to [ng2-pop-over](https://github.com/meiriko/ng2-pop-over) package. First I wanted to make a trivial test by putting a console.log into `ngOnInit` to see if I am building and `npm link`ing the package locally in the correct way, so I:

- forked and cloned the project.
- ran `npm i`
- ran `npm run build`

And got a bunch of warnings as follow below.

```
⚠️   '@angular/common' is imported by dist/index.js, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency
https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/Troubleshooting#treating-module-as-external-dependency

⚠️   '@angular/core' is imported by dist/pop-over.component.js, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency
https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/Troubleshooting#treating-module-as-external-dependency

⚠️   'rxjs/Rx' is imported by dist/pop-over.component.js, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency
https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/Troubleshooting#treating-module-as-external-dependency

⚠️   '@angular/core' is imported by dist/pop-over-trigger.directive.js, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency
https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/Troubleshooting#treating-module-as-external-dependency

⚠️   'rxjs' is imported by dist/pop-over-trigger.directive.js, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency
https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/Troubleshooting#treating-module-as-external-dependency

⚠️   '@angular/core' is imported by dist/index.js, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency
https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/Troubleshooting#treating-module-as-external-dependency

⚠️   No name was provided for external module 'rxjs/Rx' in options.globals – guessing 'rxjs_Rx'

⚠️   No name was provided for external module 'rxjs' in options.globals – guessing 'rxjs'
```

- since these were warning, I ignored them and did `npm link`
- back in my project I did `npm link ng2-pop-over`
- angular did not compile:

Failed to compile.

```
./~/ng2-pop-over/index.js
Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/user1/Code/PopoverTest/node_modules/ng2-pop-over/index.js'
    at Error (native)
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts 22:0-45
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts
```

What am I doing wrong?